# Obtain the ancestor node based on the text of a node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodes

I am trying to obtain the value of a ancestor node based on the text of the value being looked.

XML example is

```
<nodes>
   <desiredNode offset='0'>
      <secondNode a='address'>
          <value><text>alabama</text></value>
      </secondNode>
      <secondNode a='name'>
          <value><text>Taylor</text></value>
      </secondNode>
   </desiredNode>
   <desiredNode offset='1'>
      <secondNode a='address'>
          <value><text>kansas</text></value>
      </secondNode>
      <secondNode a='name'>
          <value><text>Rick</text></value>
      </secondNode>
   </desiredNode>
</nodes>
```

I want to retrieve the offset from the desiredNode based on the secondNode 'name' text (I.E. when asked for Taylor, retrieve offset '0', when asked for Rick, retrieve offse '1'

any advise?

Comment: You should write a code that you think could solve the problem, then if it doesn't work, ask on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I think you should parse XML. There XML parsers on the web, try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to retrieve the offset from the desiredNode based on the
> secondNode 'name' text (I.E. when asked for Taylor, retrieve offset
> '0', when asked for Rick, retrieve offse '1'

```
/nodes
   /desiredNode[ 
      secondNode[@a='name']
          /value/text = 'Taylor'
   ]/@offset
```

Check it [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/392fc020ed1d77812c8d6c2b943ee440)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! i was trying to get it through ancestor::* but didnt achieved the same result